# OpenGL ES - Dashed Lines

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm Using OpenGl ES 1.0 for My Android Game Development, I Want to Draw Dashed-lines
Now Im Using This Code to Draw My Line:

```java
gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
// gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
gl.glLineWidth(4.0f);
gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mBufDestVertices);
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, mDesPoly.getNumPoints());
```

How Should I Change It?
Does I have to Texture The line? And if so, How?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use a 1D texture (performance: use alpha testing instead of blending)

don't forget to:

- set texture filter to `GL_NEAREST`
- texture wrapping to `GL_REPEAT`

Comment: glLineStipple is not a core function

Comment: This needs more explanation to be useful. How use 1D texture on a line that is in 2D or 3D? There must be some formula, that is missing from this answer.  ([This link](https://developer.tizen.org/zh-hans/forums/native-application-development/gllinestipple-deprecated-opengl-es-2.0?langswitch=zh-hans) shows results that might be relevant, though I haven't looked at the code there in detail.)

Answer (score 1):

In OpenGL ES 1.0 `glLineStipple` is not supported. 1 dimensional textures are not supported, too. But 2 dimensional texturing is supported and the [Alpha test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transparency_Sorting#Alpha_test) is supported. See [OpenGL ES 1.0 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/1.0/opengles_spec_1_0.pdf).
A 1 dimensional textures, can be represented by a 2 dimensional Nx1 texture.

The stipple pattern can be encoded in a texture. Create 2 dimensional 4x1 texture with the internal format `GL_ALPHA` and the following pattern:

```non
1 0 0 1
```

The minifying and magnification function is `GL_NEAREST`. The wrap parameters are `GL_REPEAT` (that is default).

```java
byte arr[] = new byte[] { 255, 0, 0, 255 };
ByteBuffer textureBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(arr);

gl.glGenTextures(1, texture_id_, stippleTexObj);
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, stippleTexObj);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
gl.glTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_ALPHA, 4, 1, 0,
                GL10.GL_ALPHA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureBuffer);
```

When you draw the lines, the you have to enable the [Alpha test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transparency_Sorting#Alpha_test) and enable 2 dimensional texturing.

```java
gl.glAlphaFunc(GL10.GL_GEQUAL, 0.5f);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Ensure that the texture coordinates which are associated to the vertices are aligned to integral values when you draw the line, that causes the the lines start and end with a dash:

e.g. a quad with bottom left of (-0.5 -0.5) and to right of (0.5, 0.5) and the texture coordinates in range [0, 5]:

```non
 x     y       u   
-0.5f -0.5f    0.0f
 0.5f -0.5f    5.0f
 0.5f  0.5f    0.0f
-0.5f  0.5f    5.0f
```

Since the wrap function is `GL_REPEAT` and the texture coordinates are in range [0, 5], 5 repetitions of the stipple pattern are wrapped to each edge of the quad.

[image]

---

[Draw a simple dotted line or dashed line in OpenGL GLES20 android using fragment shader and GL_LINE_STRIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60293538/draw-a-simple-dotted-line-or-dashed-line-in-opengl-gles20-android-using-fragment)